(Non-) linear transformation of matrix and rank
I stumbled upon this interesting post, where OP asked whether the operation
\begin{align}
[\boldsymbol{M}^{\prime}]_{i,j} = f\left([\boldsymbol{M}]_{i,j}\right)\,
\end{align}
which is applied element-wise to the matrix $\boldsymbol{M}$ with $f$ denoting an affine transformtion is able to reduce the rank of the new matrix $\boldsymbol{M}^{\prime}$. I am curiuos, whether you know more of such transformations - properties - pairs for any other (non-linear) element-wise transformation $f$? What statements can one make about the relationship of the properties of $\boldsymbol{M}$,  $\boldsymbol{M}^{\prime}$, and the (non-linear) transformation $f$? Maybe you even know some literature regarding this topic? Thank you.

You might find my answers here and here to be helpful

So in particular, a well-researched question is whether applying $f$ to a positive-semidefinite matrix $M$ produces a positive semidefinite $M'$.

@Ben thanks for your quick reply. This is already some nice starting point I was hoping for
